# Pass combobox selected item as parameter value to class function in winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combo box that allow user to select month and year:

[image]

when I click the check button, the program will send the month and year to dbConnect.Select class there is where the programs do the select query.

```
private void cmdSend_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    List<string>[] list;
    list = dbConnect.Select(month_list.SelectedItem.ToString(),year_list.SelectedItem.ToString());

    //submit the value month and year to dbConnect.select class.
}
```

I have debug the code line by line and figure out that the line

```
list = dbConnect.Select(month_list.SelectedItem.ToString(),year_list.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

does hold the value. It suppose to pass the value to dbConnect.select class as parameter month and year.

```
public List<string>[] Select(string month,string year)
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM page_counter WHERE month = @month AND year = @year;";
    //some operations
}
```

But I found out that the public List[] Select(string month,string year) does'nt hold any value when I start the debugging.

Can someone correct me if there's any mistake in my code?

Comment: please clarify, what is the problem what your current code. Is it `month` and `year` parameter of function `Select()` is empty? if that is the case, it is likely that the cause is in the combobox. You'll need to show how it is set up and populated.

Comment: How do you bind the list in combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code as follows and execute and do accordingly

```
private void cmdSend_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{   
MessageBox.show(month_list.SelectedItem.ToString());
MessageBox.show(month_list.SelectedText.ToString());
MessageBox.show(month_list.SelectedValue.ToString());

MessageBox.show(year_list.SelectedItem.ToString());
MessageBox.show(year_list.SelectedText.ToString());
MessageBox.show(year_list.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

i think now you can understand what value to use.

Comment: Thanks, but when I test the code, I choose the month "JAN" and year "2013", and click the cmdSend_Click button, the list actually hold the value. But when it call the dbConnect.Select class, if ound out that the List<string>[] Select(string month,string year) doesnt hold any value. So I assume that this class did not fetch the parameter form cmdSend_Click. do you have any idea why?

Comment: so DBconnect is your class and select is a method in the dbconnect class, you try with harcodeing a value as dbconnect.select("1","2"); and ensure that 1 and 2 reaches in select() method and inform me the result

Comment: I try to past the value like dbconnect.select("1","2"); but still found out that the select class are empty,did not hold any value.

Comment: string query = "SELECT * FROM page_counter WHERE month ="+month+" AND year = "+year+";"; or modify the query initialization code

Comment: In  my question above is my class public List<string>[] Select(string month,string year). Is my method correct of passing the value to class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49453/discussion-between-sumeshk-and-ren)

Answer (score 0):

The SelectedItem should be from your combobox, not from the List

```
   private void cmdSend_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string>[] list;
        list = dbConnect.Select(cmdSendMonth.SelectedItem.ToString(),cmbYear.SelectedItem.ToString());

        //submit the value month and year to dbConnect.select class.
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't think this is the problem. Because when i debug by line, the list does contain value. Only in public List<string>[] Select(string month,string year) there's no value. As if like no parameters pass to the class.

Comment: What is there in dbConnect?

Comment: dbConnect is the class that connect to the database.